# If a smart card has multiple certificates on it how do go about choosing the appropriate one?

Tags: encryption, tls, cryptography, certificates, openssl

Consider a scenario where you are doing mutual TLS and you have to use a smart card to authenticate. The card has certificate and private key. How would you go about choosing which cert to use in a given connection? What would you ask the user to choose which appropriate key & cert?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the server can influence the selection of client certificate in 2 ways:

1. It can specify the acceptable CA's that signed the client certificate
2. It can specify the acceptable types of certificate ciphers

If the client has multiple suitable certificates, they will be presented with the selection dialogue.

This should be true no matter where the certificates are stored, not just on a smart card. Of course, with a card, it is possible that you might be using a client app rather than just a web browser and in that case, it would be up to the app to help clarify the purpose of each certificate and can call on data in the available certificates to assist.

With the UK's NHS smart card for example, several certificates may be present. Each one represents a clinicians role in a specific organisation and the "Identity Agent" client software presents the list in a human readable way.

This is not possible in a browser situation.